# Does combinatorial deleted product become equivalent to the topological deleted product after enough subdivision?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, configuration-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. Define the (topological) $n$-fold deleted product of $X$ to be the space or ordered $n$-tuples of pairwise distinct points in $X$.

$$F(X, n):= \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in X^n\mid i\ne j\Rightarrow x_i\ne x_j\}.$$

We are not assuming that $X$ is a manifold.

Now suppose $K$ is a geometric realization of a (finite) simplicial complex. Define the simplicial $n$-fold deleted product of $K$ to be the subspace of $K^n$ given by the union of spaces of the form $\Delta_1^{m_1}\times \cdots \times \Delta_n^{m_n}$, where $(\Delta_1^{m_1}, \ldots, \Delta_n^{m_n})$ ranges over $n$-tuples of pairwise disjoint simplices of $K$. Denote this space by $F_\Delta(K, n)$.

The space $F_\Delta(K, n)$ is a subspace of $F(K, n)$. It is well-known that for $n=2$, $F_\Delta(K, 2)$ is a $\Sigma_2$-equivariant deformation retract of $F(K, 2)$. But it is easy to see that for $n>2$ this is not always true. For example if $K=\Delta^1$ is the 1-simplex, $F_\Delta(\Delta^1, 3)$ is empty, but $F(\Delta^1,3)$ is not. So the inclusion $F_\Delta(\Delta^1, 3)\hookrightarrow F(\Delta^1,3)$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

On the other hand, it seems plausible that the inclusion becomes a homotopy equivalence one replaces $K$ with a suitable subdivision. Is it true? More precisely, the question is the following

> Fix $K$ and $n$ as above. Does there exist an $m$ such that for some iterated barycentric subdivision $sd^mK$ of $K$ the inclusion $F_\Delta(sd^mK, n)\hookrightarrow F(sd^m K,n)$ is a homotopy equivalence?

If the answer is yes I would be happy to get a reference.

Comment: It feels like one could try to use the map $F_\Delta(X,n)\rightarrow X$ that sends $x_1,..,x_n$ (which is not even a simplex) to $x_1$. The preimage of a simplex $x_1$ should be something like $F_\Delta(X\setminus B_1(x_1),n-1)$ where B_1 is the union of the interiors of all simplices that are not disjoint to $x_1$. Maybe one can then compare it with the analogous fibration for $F(X,n)$. I don't know if that works, it was just an idea. And maybe I was thinking not equivariantly enough...

Comment: one the other hand the 1-simplex really feels a bit weird. One matter how often we subdivide it, the leftmost and rightmost 1-simplices feel a bit weird. For example if $x_1$ is a fixed 1-simplex in such asubdivision, then the number of connected components of the subset $(x_1,x_2)\subset F_\Delta(X,2)$ is usually two, except for the two intervals at the end. Maybe a fomotopy equivalence has to collapse them somehow.